# How to have a loading button for <form></form>

Tags: html, css, flask

Flask/Python, HTML, CSS
Hi, I'm having trouble changing the submit button of  to a button that has a loading animation after being clicked, like this one https://codepen.io/loadingio/pen/xJvgJd
(I only have css, html, and python)

This works:

```
<form action="/output" method="post">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" name="first_name"></textarea>
    <p></p>
    <button> Submit </button>
</form>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<form action="/output" method="post">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" name="first_name"></textarea>
    <p></p>
    <div class="btn ld-ext-right"
    onclick="this.classList.add('running');" > <button> Submit</button>
    <div class="ld ld-ball ld-bounce"></div></div>
</form>
```

I'm assuming div classes can't be added to the button used in form? How can I have a form/something to take input and a loading button? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form action="/output" method="post" id="formID">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" name="first_name"></textarea>
    <p></p>
    <div class="btn ld-ext-right"
    onclick="this.classList.add('running');" > <button form="formID" type="submit"> Submit</button>
    <div class="ld ld-ball ld-bounce"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work, but thanks for the reply, I appreciate it! I think it may have to do with my project using bootstrap 4.x but the button loader animation using bootstrap 3.x?